# Add Discussions to the Network Profile

Tags: feature-request, status-review, collectives, discussions-space

I refer to the activity tab of a user's network profile fairly frequently to see what they've been up to across the network. However, it doesn't show Discussion activity, which I think would be helpful.

[Example network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/28121637/anvar?tab=activity), corresponding [Discussion activity](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21487778/anvar?tab=activity&sort=discussions)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels It's not off topic here though. This is where most of the people who would care about this feature would be, since Discussions is specific to SO.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels It would likely be closed as off-topic on MSE, as Discussions is SO only and MSE is quite diligent about closing questions that are about a single site. Here is the right place for this [tag:feature-request].

Comment: Gotca. Thank you both for clarifying this for me and for correcting me. I withdraw my statement above.

Comment: Agreed. This is in already in our backlog but lower on the immediate priority list. Status tag is set to review because this likely won't be completed for a while.